# How can I set the attribute of a field to required=True or required=False based on the value of another field?

Tags: odoo-8, required-field

I have a selection field in the `res.partner` model which is `employmentstatus` and the options there are `employed` 
or `unemployed`. I want another field `employmenttype` have the attribute `required=True` if the `employmentstatus='employed'` 
or `required=False` if the `employmentstatus='unemployed'`. The field right now sets required to True  whether Partner is 
employed or not (See attached image [here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMaZK-y77T2GqSg7UFkRSIZvsJQOnZAswvEEeY-bcQTxsFt8ACBd2Elw9vjSJOi6w?key=NVNaSDBXazdaQ0kwSWx3MF8ycDQydUJ6QUdaZm5n)).

Here is my code:

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
from openerp import tools
class custom_fields_partner(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
        'employmentstatus' : fields.selection([
        ('employed','Employed'),
        ('unemployed','Unemployed')
        ],'Employment status', required=True, default='unemployed'),
        'employmenttype' : fields.selection([
        ('0','Public'),
        ('1','Private'),
        ('2','Mission')],'Nature of employment', required="fieldproperty"),
    }

    @api.one
    def fieldproperty(self):
        if self.employmentstatus == 'employed':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 1):

The required attribute is expected to be stored in the database and is not meant to be calculated on the fly. Best bet is to do it client side. If you look in the model ir.model.fields you will notice the the required field is stored in the db and is not meant to be computed.

In your xml use the attrs attribute. Here is an example.

```
<field name="field_name" attrs="{'required':[('other_field','=','other_value')]}"/>
```

So in this example the field called `field_name` is required only if the field `other_field` has a value of `other_value` but your can create a domain criteria that is more complex or less complex depending on your needs.

The field `other_field` mush be present in your view in order for this to work because the evaluation takes place client side. If you need to include a field for evaluation but do not want to display it you can make it invisible. Like this.

```
<field name="other_field" invisible="1"/>
```